# Is there a way to list all the keys of redis with their datatypes?

Tags: redis

Suppose I have the following keys in redis:

Key names:
setkey
hashkey
zsetkey

When I enter the command on `redis-cli` : `keys *`
I get the list of all the above keys correctly. To get the data type of a specific key, we use the command `type keyname`.

Is there a way to list all the keys in redis and their data structure alongside with it? For example:

setkey set
hashkey hash
zsetkey sorted set

Is there a command/native way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should NOT use the `KEYS` command, which might block Redis for a long time. Instead, you need to use the `SCAN` command to get all keys in the database.

Secondly, before Redis 6.0, there's no native way to do that, you have to call `SCAN` to iterate the key space, and for each key, use the `TYPE` command to get its type.

Luckily, with Redis 6.0, the `SCAN` command supports `TYPE` subcommand, and you can use this subcommand to scan all keys of a specified type:

```
SCAN 0 TYPE string

SCAN 0 TYPE list
```

Check [the doc of SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) for detail. It also describe why `KEYS` is bad.